# Code signing EV certificate only helps with SmartScreen, does nothing for Windows Defender

Tags: code-signing, windows-security, windows-defender, digicert, ev-certificate

Our organization recently obtained an `EV code signing certificate`. It did give us instant `SmartScreen` trust, but 2 things still happen:

1. A minor annoyance was `Chrome` that issued a warning `file.exe is not commonly downloaded and may be dangerous` to first few downloaders but it went away within a day without us doing anything.
2. A much greater problem is `Windows Defender`. Here is what it does:

When our users install the program, it flags and locks crucial components that are required. This happens to most users.

We scanned the program components locally before uploading them and found no issues. Our `Virus & threat protection` is up to date. We also do not trigger antivirus protection when we download the same file from the website and install it as a normal user would. Why does it act so inconsistent that it doesn’t flag files when we download it from internet on our internal PC’s but it happens to most external users?

So far, we have been collecting these generic threat names and file names from our users and submitting them to Microsoft for analysis: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission
It is very admirable that MS analysts review those files within a day, but what is not good is that they seem to update their antivirus definitions only for the threat name that was detected and not mark whole file as harmless. This problem gets even more frustrating because we update our installer often since program is in active development.

I am also worried that these updates with MS threat definitions are not properly disseminated to Windows users across the world fast enough. What happens if users do not update their definitions or have them turned off?

Is there anything that we are not doing yet, but could do to reduce issues with these false positives?

EV code signing certificate was issued by DigiCert and it was very expensive. Will these issues go away after MS scans signed files several times and increases trust score of our certificate? By that I mean, will it reduce the false positives on future builds that were not yet submitted for analysis?

Comment: Any updates or new info? I'm experiencing the same Defender problem and would love to know if code signing preserves reputation across releases.